# Find a perfect Number from a range of numbers based on user input

Tags: c++, for-loop, user-input

The user inputs a number, for example 100. We need to find the perfect number in the range of 1 to the user input which is 100.

A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors excluding the number itself.

For example 6 is a perfect number, because 6 is the sum of (1, 2 and 3) which are the divisors of 6.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int input;
int sum=0;

cout << "\t Find perfect Numbers" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------- \n";
cout << "Enter an upper bound Number: ";
cin >> input;

for (int i=1; i<input; i++)
{
    for(int u=1; u<i; u++)
    {
        if (i%u == 0)
        {
            sum += u;
        }
    }
    if (sum == i)
    {
        cout << sum;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

After I run this code, it asks me to input a number and once I input a number the program exits without printing the expected result.

Comment: You need to reset `sum` to zero on each iteration of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Also, if you enter `100`, it will only print the perfect numbers between `1` and `99` inclusive. And you probably want to print a newline after the sum.

Comment: Note that you can fasten the search a little bit by using `for(int u=1; u <= i/2; u++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `sum` before the second `for` loop. If you don't, then `sum` will keep increasing over the range.

That means, for example, that before checking the case `i == 6`, the value of `sum` will be equal to 6 before entering the second loop. You will then get `sum == 12` at the end of this one and then your test will fail.

So just reset `sum` to 1 at the start (or the end) of your first loop:

```
for (int i=1; i<input; i++){

   sum = 1; // <-- Don't forget this line !

   for(int u=2; u < i/u ; u++) // Only going to square root and add u + i/u if i%u == 0
   {
      if (i%u == 0)
      {
         sum += u + i/u; // If i is divisable by u, it is divisable by i/u
      }
   }
   if (sum == i)
   {
      std::cout << sum << std::endl;
   }

}
```

As pointed out by Bob__, going to sqrt(i) and add both u and i/u at a time is enough and reduce drastically the execution time.

EDIT: reset to 1 allow to avoid 1 iteration of the loop

Comment: Note that you can limit the search of the possible divisors: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jvUXCrxlHiRSAacC

Comment: @Bob__ Good remark. Didn't think about it, as I just modified the OP code in order to give the fastest answer I could. I'm editing to take this in account

Answer (score -1):

this will get you all perfect numbers in the user range

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int input;
int sum=0;

cout << "\t Find perfect Numbers" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------- \n";
cout << "Enter an upper bound Number: ";
cin >> input;

for (int i=1; i<input; i++)
{
for(int u=1; u<i; u++)
{
    if (i%u == 0)
    {
        sum += u;

    }
}
if (sum == i){
          cout << "\n the perfect number is " <<sum;

        } 
sum = 0;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: This cannot work, as the test `sum == i` is not at the good place. Moreover, you should explain *with words* why your solution is better than OP's one (note: I did not downvote, as I assume you will improve your answer)

Comment: I misunderstood what did he want, I thought the number can be the sum of any positive divisors, otherwise he can just rest the sum after the end of the loop